# Fill Rectangle getting lost on form minimize

Tags: c#, winforms

I use the following code to fill up a panel.But whenever i minimize the form, the filled up portion of the rectangle gets lost.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
   public static void populateTable(this Panel p, int x, int y)
    {
            Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();            
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkCyan);
            g.FillRectangle(b, x, y,100,40);
            g.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: where do you invoke the function populateTable?

Comment: i do that in a background worker.. everything works fine until i minimize my form

Comment: Why not just use `panel_paint` event?

Comment: Might have to consider that then.. any ideas on this one?

Comment: I agree with  Christmas Unicorn, usually we process drawing in that OnPaint Event, because windows knows when to draw itself.

Comment: Restoring a window causes it to be completely redrawn. If your rectangle is not called in an automatic event then it will not be redrawn.

Comment: Also, not related to your problem, but you forgot to dispose of your `Brush`, it is also a lot easier to use `using` statements instead of calling `Dispose()` that way dispose still gets called in the event a exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repaint every time the panel repaints itself (For example when you restore the window from being minimized). The correct way to do this is use the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and store the objects you need to draw in some form of collection and re-draw them every call.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
    panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
}


public void PopuplateTable(int x, int y)
{
    rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(x,y, 100, 40));

    //Forces a redraw to happen.
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private List<Rectangle> rectangles; 

void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var rectangle in rectangles)
    {
        using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkCyan))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is not exactly the same as your current code, but it points you in the right direction so you can adapt your code to do the same. You may need to create a new class based on `Panel` to hold your `PopulateTable` call instead of using a extension method, if you do end up doing that you should override `OnPaint` instead of using the paint event.

```
class MyPanel : Panel
{

    private Rectangle? paintedRectangle = null;

    public void PopuplateTable(int x, int y)
    {
        paintedRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 40);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (paintedRectangle.HasValue)
        {
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkCyan))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, paintedRectangle.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```